# Error while exporting FastAI text classifier model

Tags: python, nlp, kaggle, fast-ai

I've built a text classifier using FastAi on Kaggle, while trying to export the trained model i get the following error - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

I've tried setting the leaner model directory and path to working directory.

```
learn_clas.path='/kaggle/working/'

learn_clas.model_dir='/kaggle/working/'

learn_clas.export()
```

Error i am getting is -

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastai/torch_core.py in try_save(state, path, file)     

       410 def try_save(state:Dict, path:Path=None, file:PathLikeOrBinaryStream=None):        
   --> 411     target = open(path/file, 'wb') if is_pathlike(file) else file
       412     try: torch.save(state, target)
       413     except OSError as e:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace path/file with the name of the file encased in strings.

```
target = open(path/file, 'wb') if is_pathlike(file) else file
```

In your code, python is treating path and file as variables instead of strings literals and trying to divide them. So you need some like this:

```
target = open('mydirectory/modelname.ext', 'wb') if is_pathlike(file) else file
```

or you can try

```
 target = open(path+'/'+file, 'wb') if is_pathlike(file) else file
```

Comment: Thanks @adnan-s for your answer, it makes sense how path and file variable were not treated as strings.